# HAProxy basic auth except from specific IP

Tags: haproxy, http-basic-authentication

I have set up basic authentication for my backend, like this:

```
backend webservers
    acl is_auth_ok http_auth(SiteUsers)
    http-request auth realm MySite if !is_auth_ok
```

This works but now I want to exclude a certain IP from being challenged with the authentication.

I've tried a few things but I haven't managed to get it working. To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, here's something that I've tried (this provokes a haproxy parsing error):

```
backend webservers
    acl is_internal src <<my-ip-to-exclude>>
    acl is_auth_ok http_auth(SiteUsers)
    acl is_allowed if is_internal or is_auth_ok
    http-request auth realm MySite if !is_allowed
```

Basically I'm looking to do in HAProxy the equivalent of this in Apache:

```
<Directory /var/www>
  AuthUserFile /home/www/site1-passwd
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName MySite
  Require valid-user
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from 172.17.10     <--- This allows this IP to 
  Satisfy any              <--- get in without a password
</Directory>
```

What should my HAProxy config look like?

Comment: You need to add both conditions (`is_internal` and `is_auth_ok`) to the `http-request` line, not create a new ACL with both conditions. HAProxy throws a parsing error because of the `if` in the `is_allowed` ACL line, since it's not recognized in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
backend webservers
    acl is_internal src <<my-ip-to-exclude>>
    acl is_auth_ok http_auth(SiteUsers)
    http-request auth realm MySite if !is_internal !is_auth_ok
```

This is the final working solution, thanks @GregL for pointing me in the right direction.